# Disable a specific keyboard shortcut (V) in Google Reader

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, greasemonkey, google-reader

I'd like to disable the "V" keyboard shortcut in [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/), which when selecting an item, opens that item in a new window. I'd be using JavaScript to do this, perhaps with the help of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), and doing so in [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/).

So, when "V" is hit while an item is selected, I want nothing to happen. I wouldn't know where to begin when looking through all the JavaScript that Google Reader uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sources that might be of help:

- http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/48220
- http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/25522
- http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/reader/Dr37m5-Vf1Y